# How to pass the class name of a clicked div as a parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, class, parameters

This may be basic but I could not find the result I needed in JAVASCRIPT from the research I did.

there are two number variables. they are "mainnumber" and "buttonnumber"
mainnumber is generated from math.random.
buttonnumber is the number that is at the end of the different  class names. 
That means buttonnumber = 1 when the clicked div has the class name class='example1'
That means buttonnumber = 2 when the clicked div has the class name class='example2' etc.

there are about 50 divs that have their own class name as example1,example2 etc. some class names are repeated among divs.

when a button is clicked a function "compareaction" is called to compare "mainnumber" and "buttonnumber" and do a different function called 
"resultcorrect" or "resultwrong" depending on the comparison.

// comparison code here

```
function compareaction(buttonnumber){
    if (mainnumber == buttonnumber){
        resultcorrect();    
    } else {
        resultwrong();
    }
}
```

I need to know how to pass the number at the end of class name (that is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 etc) to the function.

```
<div class="example1" onclick="compareaction(\\number in class name as a parameter)"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there will be only 1 class on the element ever? if not, it's better to use a custom `data-` attribute than a classname.

Answer (score 3):

Pass class name to function

```
<div class="example1" onclick="compareaction(this.className)">
```

then check it inside function

```
function compareaction(className) {
    // className will be 'example1' in this case
    var buttonNumber = className.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    if (mainnumber == buttonNumber){
        resultcorrect();    
    } else {
        resultwrong();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But I need to compare the last number of the class name or else pass only the last number of the class name. The code you explained passes the name "example1" whereas I need to pass only "1".

Comment: Better to work with class name inside function, for example using regex: `className.match(/\d+$/)[0]`

Comment: I would suggest to not use class name for that purposes, and use data-attribute to store data in it: `<div data-number="1" onlick="analyse">` and in analyse function get this attribute using `this.getAttribute('data-number')`

Comment: Sorry for bothering , but could you please explain className.match(/\d+$/)[0]  I am new to js. :)

Comment: that means that we want to match one or more digits at the end of class name using regular expression /\d+$/, which returns array of matched tokens, in this case - number you are looking for: example1 -> 1, example2 -> 2, example37 -> 37